# All files of a dir in tar as file-like obj

Tags: python, tar

there is a simple way to get all files inside a specifically dir (dir that is in a tar file) one after another as a same file-like object?

TNX

Comment: did you look at the tarfile package? That seems like the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TarFile.getmembers()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getmembers) to get all the entries in a tarball, and iterate through them to filter the ones you want. Pass each in turn to [`TarFile.extractfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) to get a file-like to the entry within the tarball.